# Burn or tag "paint" and "painting" as synonymous tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Isn't [paint](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paint) and [painting](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/painting) so close that one of them should either be burned or marked as a synonym of the other?

The definitions as of 2015-05-31 are:

- [paint](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paint) - Hacks related to applying and removing paint from various surfaces or [cleaning](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning) paint and [cleaning](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning) of paint.
- [painting](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/painting) - Hacks related to painting, which may include application, removal, or [storage](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fully agree with this request.

### The [painting](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/painting) has been merged into [paint](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paint)